# NuGet Package Manager Console returns InvalidOperation when trying to install the ZXing.Net library

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019, zxing.net

I am trying to install the ZXing.Net library to VisualStudio 2019 to use in Unity but entering the command in the console returns a category of InvalidOperation

I just copy pasted the code right our of ZXing.Net in nuget.org but it returned this error:

```
PM> Install-Package ZXing.Net -Version 0.16.5

Install-Package : The current environment doesn't have a solution open.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  ZXing.Net -Version 0.16.5
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetNoActiveSolution,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Install-Package : The current environment doesn't have a solution
>   open.

Just as the error message indicates, please check if you have one solution with at least one project open in Visual Studio. If you run the command in when there's `no solution open`(It means you don't create or even open a project), that's the expected behavior that you get that error.

When you use the command `Install-Package ZXing.Net -Version 0.16.5` in Package Manager Console, you should at least make sure the specific project is selected in `Default Project` drop-down list. See [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio#package-manager-console).

> For normal situation:

If we create a new simple C# console or class library project, make sure the project is selected in Package Manager Console window, then the command can succeed to install that package into **current project**. (Also it will install the package into [global-package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) folder:`%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`)

> I am trying to install the ZXing.Net library to VisualStudio 2019 to
>   use in Unity

To be honest, I'm not certainly sure what you're meaning... If you're just trying to install that package into Global-packages folder, you can simply create a new C# project and run that command.(like what I described in `For normal situation`)

Maybe what you actually need to do is to install that package into your [C# script project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/using-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2019#open-unity-scripts-in-visual-studio)? If so, you can also try to install that package by VS UI, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/using-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2019#to-debug-a-managed-dll-project-used-in-your-unity-project), after you **open your C# script project(from Unity) in Visual Studio**, right-click it in `Solution Explorer` to use the `Manage Nuget Packages` UI, then you can use the UI to search that package and install specific version like using command-line. See:

[image]

Hope it helps :)